# How can I store user id in a session which can be used to echo out in the web page? PHP session

Tags: php, html, mysql, session, userid

I have two pages which are login.php and home.php. Here login.php will set the sessions which are userid and username. Alongside home.php will echo out the details based on the session user id. I am having a problem on storing the user id and it doesn't echo out the details. Is there any solution?

login.php

```
        session_start(); 
         if(isset($_POST['loginbtn']))
        {
         $username = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i','',$_POST['username']); 
         $password =preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i','',$_POST['password']); 

    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname','',''); 

    $sql = "SELECT teacher_id, username, password FROM teacher 
    WHERE username =:username and password =:password"; 

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql); 

    $stmt->bindParam(":username", $_POST['username']); 
    $stmt->bindParam(":password", $_POST['password']); 
    $stmt->execute(); 

    if($result=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
    {
        $dbid = $row['teacher_id']; 
        $_SESSION['valid_teacherId'] = $dbid; 

        $dbuser = $row['username']; 
        $_SESSION['valid_username'] = $username; 

        $dbpass = $row['password']; 

        if ($password && $username)
        {
            header("location: home.php?teacher=" .$username);  
        } 
    else {
    echo "Please input username or password"; 
  }
        } 
    else{
        echo "Please insert a valid username or password"; 
    }
} else{
        header("location: index.php");  
}
 ?>
```

home.php

```
 <?php
 error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); 
 session_start();
 $userid = $_SESSION['valid_teacherId']; 
 $username = $_SESSION['valid_username']; 
 ?>

<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "", "dbname");
 if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

  $result = mysqli_query ($con,"SELECT * FROM classroom WHERE teacher_id = $userid");

 echo '<table class="table" border="2">
 <tr>
   <th>Year</th>
   <th>Class no</th>
   <th>Section</th>
    </tr>';

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

     {
     echo "<tr>
       <td>" . $row['year'] . "</td>
      <td>" . $row['class_no'] . "</td>
     <td>" . $row['section'] . "</td>
      </tr>";
    }
      echo "</table>";
       ?>
```

Comment: Store `$_POST['username']` in `$_SESSION['username']`? Of course you would need `start_session()` at the top of each page where you expect to use the session array.

Comment: @JayBlanchard, In home page or the login page? I have used $_SESSION['valid_username'] in login page to set session.

That would be for username, what about for userid?

Comment: `session_start()` must be at the top of every page that you expect to be session aware.

Comment: You are just removing invalid characters in username and password?  This is really bad idea.  Why should `my password` be treated the same as `mypassword`? Instead you should tell the user they have invalid syntax so they can correct it and not rely on some behavior that they know nothing about.

Comment: @JayBlanchard, just to remind you, I have session_start() in all the pages but still it doesn't work.

Comment: @MikeBrant, so u ant me to remove preg_replace command?

Comment: You really shouldn't place any limits on user passwords. It is just bad UX to do so. I use pass phrases (much more secure IMHO) and your removal of things limits me on that.

Comment: @user3242329 Yes. It really bad if the user, for example, creates a user name like `some user` but the system actually treats it like `someuser` without the user knowing about it.  If you want to enforce some syntax, do in some manner that the user can see it (i.e. enforce in client as well as on server).  Don't just blindly change the values being sent in.

Comment: Enable proper error_reporting __now__ … and give PHP a chance to tell you about your most basic eff-ups itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're assignin a null value to `$dbid` and `$dbuser` there is no `$row` object witch contains your extracted data from database:

```
if($result=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
    $dbid = $result->teacher_id; 
    $_SESSION['valid_teacherId'] = $dbid; 
    $dbuser = $result->username; 
    $_SESSION['valid_username'] = $username; 
    $dbpass = $result->password; 
    if (isset($password) && isset($username)) header("location: home.php?teacher=" .$username);  
}else
    echo "Please input username or password";
```

Then in your `home.php` script you should check if the session in actually set by using isset.

```
$userid = $_SESSION['valid_teacherId']; 
$username = $_SESSION['valid_username']; 

if (isset($userid) && isset($username)) {
    //continue
    //here
}else{
    //user is not logged in
    echo "Please login!";
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error saying Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: Updated, check now, that's because fetch() method returns an object, not an array

Comment: Thanks Cristian. You are damn AWESOME. just one word, AWESOME.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your issue -

```
if($result=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) // requesting $result
    {
        $dbid = $row['teacher_id'];  // using $row
        $_SESSION['valid_teacherId'] = $dbid; 

        $dbuser = $row['username']; // using $row
        $_SESSION['valid_username'] = $username; 

        $dbpass = $row['password']; // using $row
```

You need to change `$row` to `$result` or vice-versa and you need to use the object references:

```
if($result=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) // requesting $result
        {
            $dbid = $row->teacher_id;  // using $row, note syntax change
            $_SESSION['valid_teacherId'] = $dbid; 

            $dbuser = $row->username; // using $row, note syntax change
            $_SESSION['valid_username'] = $username; 

            $dbpass = $row->password; // using $row, note syntax change
```